# How can I find the collision response between a moving sphere and cube?

Tags: 3d, collision-resolution

I'm implementing my own algorithm for sphere and cube collision response. So far I'm able to only test if both of them overlap.

My problem is: A cube is rotating around its axes i.e x and z axes. And the sphere is moving at a velocity that being Vx,Vy and Vz in all the 3 axes. How do I find the collision response between them without considering angular velocity of cube i.e when the cube and sphere collide cube is not having an velocity but angles with 2 axes. After collision I don't want the sphere to have angular velocity.

Comment: Will your cube be moving afterwards, or is its position fixed?

Comment: There are a lot of different collision response types. The simplest one is to just move them such that they are not penetrating anymore.

Comment: @didierc Cube remains fixed and its mass can be considered much more than sphere. So, when sphere collides it just reflects back and cube maintains its rotation.

Comment: Ok then, so it's equivalent to a reflection on a hard plane like surface. How about simply moving back the sphere along its moving direction (given by its current speed vector) til contact point, then applying the reflection calculation?

Comment: @user9 The question says the cube "is rotating". Your comment says it "remains fixed". Which is it?

Comment: Rotating and not translating. i.e rotating at a fixed position.